# Tutorial Solidity Oracle error: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable

Tags: solidity, remix, oracles, provable

I am deploying an oracle contract on Remix. I am able to successfulyl deploy the contract, but when I try to call the updatePrice() function, I keep getting the error: "The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."

I have tried to use oracle code from a couple of different tutorials, but I keep getting the same error message for all of them. I don't think the error is with the code itself but perhaps in my setup.

I'm using compiler version 0.4.25. I'm using JavaScript VM. I start by compiling, then deploying the contract using JavaScript VM with 1 ethereum. Then I call the updatePrice() function as I send in 1 ethereum. Then I get the error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;
import "github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/provableAPI_0.4.25.sol";

contract ExampleContract is usingProvable {

    string public ETHUSD;
    event LogConstructorInitiated(string nextStep);
    event LogPriceUpdated(string price);
    event LogNewProvableQuery(string description);

    function ExampleContract() payable {
        LogConstructorInitiated("Constructor was initiated. Call 'updatePrice()' to send the 
Provable Query.");
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
        if (msg.sender != provable_cbAddress()) revert();
        ETHUSD = result;
        LogPriceUpdated(result);
    }

    function updatePrice() payable {
        if (provable_getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
            LogNewProvableQuery("Provable query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
        } else {
            LogNewProvableQuery("Provable query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
            provable_query("URL", "json(https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).price");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Remix screenshot]